# browser sync and jest set-up environment

Tags: javascript, jestjs, browser-sync

I have browser sync and jest installed but browser sync does not because of the module.exports() that jest uses for testing. I know module is not supported on the server side so what do I have to do get browser sync and jest to work together so that it ignores the module.exports?

Do I have to use Gulp or Grunt to build the test environment and then pass it to browser sync so the module.exports don't carry over? Or is there something else I should configure?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Had to use Gulp for the building of Dev files and a watch so that that browser sync runs when updated.

Workflow is:

Code > Save > Tests run > Built Dev > Run  browser sync